# Globalization unable to find appropriate resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

I'm trying to globalize an mvc application (french and english), here's what I did:

1) Created an App_LocalResources folder and added 2 files:

- Resources.resx (will contain french) and
- Resources.en.resx (will contain english).

Then I added one resource in each file with the same name (just to test) and modified the access modifier to Public (for each file)

2) Specified the french culture in global.asax

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    string userLanguage = Request.UserLanguages[0];
    string cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(userLanguage);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    HRP.App_LocalResources.Resources.Culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
}
```

CultureHelper is a helper I found online, it determines the correct name of the culture (credits to the author):  http://pastebin.com/JkhjJg4N

3) Added a test string to display in my view:

```
<p><span class="Title">@HRP.App_LocalResources.Resources.EmployeesTitle</span></p>
```

And the exception is:

```
[MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "HRP.App_LocalResources.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "HRP" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.]
```

Please help.

Comment: Is the userLanguage french? Try adding a Resource.fr.resx and see if it works.

Comment: I just tried it on my own and it work pretty well. Did you check `List<string> _cultures` property in *CultureHelper* class to contain those cultures you provide?

Comment: @HariHaraChandan I added the Resource.fr.resx and it's the same.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz CultureHelper contains the cultures that I need.

Comment: what values do your get for `userLanguage` and `cultureName`?

Comment: when my locale is english it's userLanguage is "en" and cultureName is "en-US"

Comment: I think I solved it !

Comment: Did you changed buildAction to *embedded ressource* and used the custom tool *PublicResXFileCodeGenerator* on your resource files?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz changing the build action solved it. Answer and I will accept it if you want but why should I use the custom tool ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a small example showing how your code should work out.

1. Set the build action of the resources to **embedded resource**
2. Enter custom tool **PublicResXFileCodeGenerator**

Afterwards your resources will be available within your code

*razor file*

```
<p>@NAMESPACE.App_LocalResources.YOUR_RESOURCE_FILE.RESOURCE_NAME</p>
```

I have used another custom tool as [K. Scott Allen stated](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx)

> **Resx Files Outside Of Special Resource Directories resx properties in MVC**
>
> If you add a resx file to any other folder in an MVC project or
>   class library, the resx is automatically set to be embedded into the
>   project’s output assembly - this is good. The IDE also assigns the
>   resx a custom tool of ResxCodeFileGenerator to generate a strongly
>   typed wrapper - this is good. The **generated class is internal by**
>   **default – this is bad**. The assembly created for a view (by ASP.NET)
>   won’t be able to use the internal class because it is in a different
>   assembly – the project assembly compiled in Visual Studio.

So if you add your resource files to the special folders - anything goes right. If you choose to place it on another path it would fail (unless you use the custom tool).

Answer (score 3):

I solved it thanks to a friend's tip:
the problem was that the .resx files were builded as Content so all I needed to do was:

Right click on your ResourceFile -> Properties -> Change the "Build Action" property from "Content" to "Embedded Resource"